# How to calculate how many days lef to due date in a query?

Tags: python, django

I have a model that has `due_date` field and I want to create a query that annotates overdue value that counts how many days are left until due_date.
but I can't implement it in my code I'm getting this error:

```
Case() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default'
```

and if I remove the default I get:

```
 TypeError: QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s):
```

PS: Some of the objects have null due_date

```
 query_list = file.qs.annotate(overdue=Case(
            When(due_date__gt=timezone.now().date(), then=Value((F('due_date') - timezone.now().date()))),
            When(due_date__isnull=True, then=Value(None)),
            default=Value(0),
            output_field=DurationField())).values_list('overdue', ...)
```